# How to override global variable in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

First of all, it sounds like this situation is perfect of use `eventBus` but I am just experimenting. What I feel this will element the process of emitting and capturing event.

Say that in my main.js I have declared:

```
Vue.prototype.$someHeight = 200
```

in some of my component I tried to change it to:

```
this.$someHeight = 300
```

But when I use it in my vue, it still says:
 {{ $someHeight }} // output: 200, and I was expecting 300

So, how to override it? Is this a good practice?

Comment: This is something you normally do in a vuex store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every vue component is an instance of Vue. When you define a variable (such as  $someHeight) on Vue's prototype, all new components created will get their own **copy** of such variable.

Which means every Vue component will have its own copy of $someHeight with value of 200. Now even if you set its value to 300, all other components will have the old value of 200.

It is not a good practice. You should only define functions on prototype: [Vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Context-of-Prototype-Methods)

Now you can either use Vuex for this or create a global vue instance and use it to store your global variables. Vuex recommended of-course!

Comment: application is too small size, i can't use vuex for such a small thing. what should we need to do except vuex

Comment: Then just declare a vue instance and use it everywhere.

Comment: could you give me an example please?  using code